# Android Native TextField with input type password is not working properly when making plugin for unity

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I am working on a unity plugin but my Edit text field with input type password is not working properly when I input the numeric values, it does not allow me to input. for example when I am entering a password it would allow me to enter alphabets and all the symbols but when I start entering numeric characters it stops taking input.

```
EditText ET1 = new EditText(getActivity());
            ET1.setLayoutParams(params);
            ET1.addTextChangedListener(generalTextWatcher);

            ET1.setId(id);
            ET1.setHint(hintText);
            ET1.setText(Preloaded_Text);
            ET1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

This code is working fine on native android app but when making plugin for unity it does not show the same behavior can someone guide if I need to provide something extra in manifest or anything if you think that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` as additional parameter for `setInputType` function.

Comment: I have already tried this thing but it isnt working they I wanted it to work.

Comment: Numeric characters from 1-0 is accepted by the Edit text when Input type is password when creating it in unity or you can say when using it as a unity android plugin